# Show Currency sign for negative values

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

my report consists of a few positive and negative values. The positive values seem to be showing the currency sign correctly however the negative values remove the currency sign.

My current code is:
=IIF(Me.Value > 0, "$##,##", "##,##")

This provides me with the following results. 
[image: Image of results]

On the left side, you can see the positive values with the currency sign but on the right side, it has negative values yet with no currency sign.

Is it possible to have the right side show a currency as well. (E.g. -$1,229,655 or $-1,229,655)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Think I may have solved my own question. Method i used was

=IIF(Me.Value > 0, "$##,##",IIF(Me.Value < 0, "$#,###", "##,##"))

Providing me with currency symbol if it is a positive value or a negative value, and if the value is empty, it doesn't show anything.

Comment: IF local currency is acceptable, you can simply set the format of the cell/textbox to `C`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the expression to `=Iif( Me.Value <> 0, "$#,###", "#")`

The same can be done in a more simple way, without `Iif` by setting the format property to
`="$#,#.##;-$#,#.##;#"`

The format expression consists of three parts: the first part is for positive numbers, the second for negative and the third for zero values. Each part is separated by a semicolon. The second and third parts are the same as the positive numbers if ommited.